# Does deleting an old object, and adding a new object with the same primary keys cause an issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I was wondering if anyone has experienced a problem like mine. I'm currently writing a method that parses an array of information I need to persist in my Realm db.

```
RLMRealm *defaultRealm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction];
[defaultRealm deleteObject:myOldObjectWithPrimaryKey1];
[defaultRealm commitWriteTransaction];

...do some work....

[defaultRealm beginWriteTransaction];
[defaultRealm addOrUpdateObject:myNewObjectWithPrimaryKey1];
[defaultRealm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Is this a legitimate thing to do in Realm? I'm noticing my values are not being updated/stored properly.

Thanks!

Comment: While it does not "cause an issue", the object itself will become invalid, and you'll have to requery the "new object with same primary key".

Comment: Do you see any error messages? The code sample you provided seems fine to me.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce
I understand myOldObjectWithPrimaryKey1 would become invalid, but I'm not trying to access that object anymore. myNewObjectWithPrimaryKey1 is a completely newly allocated object... the only same thing between the two objects are that they share the same primary key value. In this case, they both share the primary key value 1.

Comment: @Dmitry No I do not see any errors... I'm just trying to figure out why sometimes the db doesn't persist the data. It appears though that it has to do with when I call writeCopyToPath to compress the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem didn't lie with having the same primary key values. The issue lied again with when I called writeCopyToPath to compress the database size, something screwed up and caused the database to revert to an older state and thus data was missing.

Comment: Can you share an example Xcode project that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Sounds like the file system operations you're doing might be racey.